# Convert a controller into a component

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-components

How do I convert a controller into a component and then include it in another component as a dependency?

I would like to do this in order to be able to use certain functions which are in this controller in a component, which has an isolated scope.

My controller:

```
angular
.module('myApp')
.controller('TaxiesController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$routeParams', '$route', 'dataFactory', '$interval', function($scope, $http, $location, $routeParams, $route, dataFactory, $interval){
    console.log('TaxiesController loaded')
    var cancel = {name: 'Preklic', price: 500}
    $scope.taxies = [];
    $scope.taxi = {};
    $scope.taxi.history = [];

    $scope.getTaxies = () => {
        //console.log('X')
        dataFactory.getTaxies().then(function(response){ //make a get req from this address
            $scope.taxies = response.data; 
        });
    }

    $scope.getTaxi = () => {
        var id = $routeParams.id;
        dataFactory.getTaxi(id).then(function(response){ 
            $scope.taxi = response.data; //to moram uporabit, da dobim taxi
        });
    }

    $scope.removeTaxi = (id) => {
        dataFactory.removeTaxi(id).then(function(response){ 
            //window.location.href='#!'; 
        });
    }

    $scope.getTotal = (taxi) => {
        var total = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < taxi.history.length; i++){ // deluje tudi z $scope.taxi.history.length
            var rent = taxi.history[i];
            if(rent.price) total += rent.price;
        }
        return total;
    }

    $scope.cancelTaxi = (taxi, id) => {
        console.log('cancelling..')
        taxi.available = true;
        taxi.history.unshift(cancel);
        dataFactory.updateTaxi(id, taxi).then(function(response){ 
        });
    }


}]);
```

Comment: If the other component is mostly presentational, I'd pass in the functions to be invoked as callbacks by the other component. Otherwise you could put the functionality in a service and inject it into the other component.

Comment: And how do I put it in a service? If you can't show me exactly how to do it, I'd ask you to point me to an example that shows it.

Comment: You already have a service (factory is basically the same thing) called `dataFactory`. Look at how that was built.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `$scope` with the ['`this`'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) object:

```
app.controller('TaxiesController', function(dataFactory){
    console.log('TaxiesController loaded')
    var vm = this;
    vm.taxies = [];

    vm.getTaxies = () => {
        //console.log('X')
        dataFactory.getTaxies().then(function(response){ //make a get req from this address
            vm.taxies = response.data; 
        });
    }

    //Other functions

});
```

And instantiate it in the component:

```
app.component({
    controller: 'TaxiesController',
    template: `
        <button ng-click="$ctrl.getTaxies()">Get Taxies</button>
        <div ng-repeat="taxi in $ctrl.taxies">
             {{taxi | json }}
        </div>
    `
});
```

Components instantiate their controllers using the `controllerAs` property with the default value of `$ctrl`.

For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Understanding Components](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component).